# Plane tracker in Meta Spark AR

Tags: spark-ar-studio

I do not know what to do with this problem. I can not use the plane tracker. I already updated everything: metasparkar, instagram and the app on my cell phone. I did the basics: a plane tracker and a 3D cube and in the app I can't run it.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks.